# Rundeck 3.3.6 Community - Move from H2 Db to MySql 8.0

Tags: mysql, rundeck

My Ansible/Rundeck host is an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system. I installed Ansible to tinker and then installed Rundeck. Once I was able to get the two talking and working properly (in my mind), I thought it would be best to move Rundeck to a production level DB engine instead of H2. I installed MySQL on the same host and setup the DB and the DB user as directed in the Rundeck docs. I then modified the RD properties file as the same document instructs but I keep getting a failure to connect to the database.

First it was this error:

> WARN  internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000341: Could not obtain connection metadata : Could not connect to address=(host=10.10.140.23)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:10.10.140.23, port:3306. Connection refused (Connection refused)

So then I researched the issue and it suggested to validate the user account in MySQL, grants, access, etc. - It all works from a command line testing in MySQL.

I read in one of my searches that some people had luck with removing the useSSL=false or setting it to true. That led to my next error of:

> WARN  internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000341: Could not obtain connection metadata : Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : RSA public key is not available client side (option serverRsaPublicKeyFile)

During my research on this error, I read that I needed to add a property to allow the retrieval of the RSA keys, and I did but it didn't change a thing.

I then downloaded the Oracle MySQL jdbc driver and placed it in the var/lib/rundeck/lib folder and changed the driver class name in the properties file and then I received my next error of

> WARN  internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000341: Could not obtain connection metadata : Could not connect to address=(host=127.0.0.1)(port=3306)(type=master) : (conn=355) Access denied for user 'sa'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
> Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'

when I attempted to run Rundeck.

At this point I am back on H2 and I am too much of a Linux novice to understand what the issue may be. Can anyone kindly point me in a direction that helps as the Rundeck docks for using a MySQL DB seem to either be old or missing some content as a lot of the searches I have made on trying to resolve the issue directs me to perform things slight differently or all new commands that the Rundeck docs don't even mention.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed same issue stopping the Rundeck instance, later adding the following config on the `rundeck-config.properties` file (at `/etc/rundeck` path, check [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/mysql.html#configure-rundeck)):

```sh
# works with allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql_server_ip/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
dataSource.username=rundeckuser
dataSource.password=your_password
dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# to store projects on backend
rundeck.projectsStorageType=db
```

Next, flushing the connections on the database side with `mysqladmin flush-hosts -u root -p`.

Now, starting your Rundeck service, you can [check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScHgP.jpg) that is using MySQL 8 as a data source for your projects.

EDIT: On the MySQL side, make sure that you've created the user properly, I followed these steps:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE rundeck;
CREATE USER 'rundeckuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'P4ssw0rd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON rundeck.* TO 'rundeckuser'@'%';
exit;
```

Also [check](https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/issues/2201#issuecomment-474275217) how MySQL 8 is storing the user's passwords.

Comment: I wish that had worked but my result was: "WARN  internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000341: Could not obtain connection metadata : Access denied for user 'sa'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: Make sure that you've created the user properly on MySQL (I updated the answer)

Comment: I have per the docs and I validated that I could connect to MySQL with that user and see the grants and database, which in this case is called rundeckdb.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/issues/2201#issuecomment-474275217 maybe is a problem with the password type.

Comment: I was able to detect in the system.log output: ' Unable to load class: com.mysql.jc.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:org.springframework.boot.loader.'.  Obviously the MySQL jdbc driver is not being loaded or possibly found at all. I placed the file in /var/lib/rundeck/lib. Do I need to give the file any special permissions or should it be named something specific. I used wget to download it while in Ubuntu. The file name is mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar.